# Django 1.4 - Add custom error message to user fields in form with meta field Model=User

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, metaclass, custom-errors

I was trying to add some custom error messages to a form like this one:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User  
        fields = ('email',)

    extra_field = forms.CharField(error_messages={
        'required':'Este campo es requerido'
    })
```

I have no problem adding custom error messages to a field that is declared in the form (`extra_field`), but I'm having trouble adding custom error messages to the fields inherited from the model `User` via `meta` class (`email`).

What I really want is to customize all the error messages of this form. Also, I would like to display them in spanish, not english.

So far I have not found any documentation about how to customize the form fields inherited from the model User, I don't really want to write a new form just because of the error messages.

Thanks in advance!!!

PD: I'm using Django 1.4 and python 2.6.6 in a debian squeeze box.

Comment: What benefit in adding custom error to `error_messages` dict? You just can do `raise forms.ValidationError('The important message')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, thank you all for your answers, in fact you helped me a lot!!!

I solved the problem like this:

Suposse I have this form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = User  
    fields = ('username', 'email')
```

And I want to add custom error messages to the username field, but I don't want to loose all the validation that already comes with that field.

I added this method to my RegistrationForm class:

```
def clean_username(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data

    # My extremely important validation.
    if len(data['username']) == 5:

      self.fields['username'].error_messages["myerror"] = "The important message"
      raise forms.ValidationError(self.fields['username'].error_messages["myerror"])

    return data['username']
```

The advantage of this aproach is that I don't loose the other validation checks that already come with the field in question.

This is important because now I don't have to validate that the user already exists in my database.

Thanks for your responses, have a good day!!!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on internalization in your [settings.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/)

```
USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
```

Model `User` doesn't differ from others. Put your code to figure out the issue.
In your meta class `fields = ('email')` must be tuple or list, i.e. `fields = ('email', )`

Comment: Hi San4ez, thank you very much for your answer, I have fixed the fields value of the meta class, and the internationalization issue, however, I still don't know how to customize the User's model form without hacking in it's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any of the inherited fields by simply redefining them in exactly the same way as you have defined your extra field.

Comment: The problem with this aproach is that I would loose all the preexistent validation rules that come with that field. For instance lets say that I redefine the field username. I would have to provide all the validation related to the uniqueness of that username manually.